# SyntaxError:invalid token -Python Lists

Tags: python

I have a list, created from a CSV file that contains dates. When trying to get the index of a date, I get the correct line (File "", line 1) but also get an error:

```
    calendarData.index([01/01/20])
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

The file looks like this:

```
>>> calendarData
[['01/01/20'], ['01/02/20'], ['01/03/20'], ['01/04/20'], ['01/05/20'], ['01/06/20'], ['01/07/20'], ['01/08/20'], ['01/09/20'], ['01/10/20'], ['01/11/20'], ['01/12/20'], ['01/13/20'], ['01/14/20'], ...
```

This is the request:

```
>>> calendarData.index([01/01/20])
```

This response looks correct (but I would rather just get 1 as a return)
File "", line 1

Then this error:

```
    calendarData.index([01/01/20])
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Two questions:

1. What's the SyntaxError about? How do I get rid of it?
2. How do I get the return to only equal 1 ( the index num), not 'File "", line 1'

Comment: `01/01/20` is a string.  Put quotes around it.  `calendarData.index(['01/01/20'])`

Comment: @JohnGordon please post your comment as an answer